# Django(2.1.4): How to get path variable from all request in middleware?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am new to python(3)/Django(2.1.4) framework. I want to get path variable which is present in all urls in my middleware. I tried something below but its not working for me.

URLS:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/v1/mywebsite/<uuid:path_variable_name>/', include('website.urls')),
]
```

Middleware :

```
class my_middle_ware(MiddlewareMixin):

def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response

def __call__(self, request):
    print(request.GET.get['path_variable_name'])
    print(request.POST.get['path_variable_name'])
    response = self.get_response(request)
    return response
```

I want to fetch `path_variable_name` in my middleware. Instead of using request.GET, request.POST and so on , Is there any generic way to intercept all request request.getPathVariable('path_variabl_name') ? Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You would probably have to use [process_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#process_view), looking at the time when [url is resolved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match).

Comment: Hey @mfrackowiak, Thanks. It works.

Comment: @mfrackowiak please provide answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are not available until [the url is resolved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.resolver_match). However, class based middlewares also have an available hook [`process_view`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pl/2.1/topics/http/middleware/#process_view), where `view_args` and `view_kwargs` are available - the parameter from url will be in one of them.

Comment: can it possible fetch model from database in middleware ? if yes then how ?

Comment: I want to do this. can you provide any link or example for this.

Comment: I think it should be pretty straightforward, with just importing the model and using it as in any other place.

Comment: ohh, I thought in that way but not sure. lets try me this one.